# I am working with the source code of RSA Algorithm.It compiles correctly with no errors but the output is not correct

Tags: c, linux, gcc, cryptography, rsa

I am working with the source code of RSA Algorithm and there are no errors in following code compilation but few warnings with respect to incorrect flags.But the output is not as it should be.
Source Code:

```
#include<stdio.h>
int phi,M,n,e,d,C,FLAG;
int check()
{
int i;
for(i=3;e%i==0 && phi%i==0;i+2)
{
 FLAG = 1;
 return 0;
}
FLAG = 0;
return 0;
}

void encrypt()
{
int i;    
C = 1;
for(i=0;i< e;i++)
C=C*M%n;
C = C%n;
printf("\n\tEncrypted keyword : %d",C);
}
void decrypt()
{
int i;
 M = 1;
for(i=0;i< d;i++)
M=M*C%n;
M = M%n;
printf("\n\tDecrypted keyword : %d",M);
}

int main()
{    system("clear");
 int p,q,s;
 printf("Enter Two Relatively Prime Numbers\t: ");
 scanf("%d%d",&p,&q);
 n = p*q;
 phi=(p-1)*(q-1);
 printf("\n\tF(n)\t= %d",phi);
 do
 {
  printf("\n\nEnter e(less than F(n)\t: ");
  scanf("%d",&e);
  check();
 }while(FLAG==1);
 d = 1;
 do
  {
     s = (d*e)%phi;
     d++;
  }while(s!=1);     
  d = d-1;
   printf("\n\tPublic Key\t: {%d,%d}",e,n);
   printf("\n\tPrivate Key\t: {%d,%d}",d,n);
   printf("\n\nEnter The Plain Text\t: ");
   scanf("%d",&M);
   printf("\n \n");
   printf("\n\nEnter the Cipher text\t: ");
   scanf("%d",&C);
   encrypt();
   decrypt();
   getchar();
   }
```

output of the above code snippet -

[image: Output Image]

Any suggestions to solve incorrect output response?

Comment: Please paste the session transcript into the talk instead of linking to an image.

Comment: The code could use a little bit of coherent indentation.

Answer (score 2):

Your program expects a number as the plain text. You pass the string `"hi"`. What did you expect to happen?

Next time, consider checking the return value of `scanf`. It indicates how many items were successfully scanned. Use this to find out if the user actually typed a number.